# Get one script to cycle through multiple variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that rates the top 15 websites one the web (from Alexa), and it uses javascript to write the new ratings, but this is very inefficient. There are 6 variables for each rating. And it writes one code block for each rating, using the variables. Is there a way to just make it use one code block to write all 15 of the ratings? Here is some code:

```
var topID1 = 1;
var topWidth1 = 100;
var topPageURL1 = 'www.google.com'
var topPageTitle1 = 'Google';
var topRate1 = rateStar9;
var topMargin1 = 0;

$('#topSites1').html('<div class="meter-wrap" style="margin-top: ' + topMargin1 + 'px;"><div class="meter-value" style="background-color: ' + topSitesBack + '; width: ' + topWidth1 + '%;"><div class="meter-text"><span class="toplist"><span class="topnum">' + topID1 + '. </span><span class="favico" id="ico1"><img src="img/blank.gif" style="width:16px;height:16px;"></img></span><a href="http://' + topPageURL1 + '/">' + topPageTitle1 + '</a><span class="rating" style="width: ' + topRate1 + 'px;"><img src="img/blank.gif" style="width:100%;height:16px;"></img></span></span></div></div></div>');
$('#ico1').css('background', 'url(' + topPageFavicon + topPageURL1 + ') no-repeat');
```

(repeat both 15 times)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its called using a javascript object. than you can itterate through the object to get you info:

```
var all_ratings = {

    'GOOGLE': {
        topID: 1,
        topWidth: 100,
        topPageURL: 'something',
        topPageTitle: 'something_else',
        topRate: rateStar,
        topMargin: 'something'
    },

    'YAHOO': {
        topID: 1,
        topWidth: 100,
        topPageURL: 'something',
        topPageTitle: 'something_else',
        topRate: rateStar,
        topMargin: 'something'
    },
    ..MORE
}
```

Than you can do (using `$.each`): (since i believe you are using jQuery):

```
$.each(all_ratings, function (index, item)
{
    var outerDiv = $('<div>', {
        'class': 'meter-wrap',
        style: 'margin-top: ' + item.topMargin + 'px;'
    }),
        innerDiv = $('<div class="meter-value" style="background-color: ' + topSitesBack + '; width: ' + item.topWidth + '%;">').html('<div class="meter-text"><span class="toplist"><span class="topnum">' + item.topID + '. </span><span class="favico" id="ico1"><img src="img/blank.gif" style="width:16px;height:16px;"></img></span><a href="http://' + item.topPageURL + '/">' + item.topPageTitle + '</a><span class="rating" style="width: ' + item.topRate + 'px;"><img src="img/blank.gif" style="width:100%;height:16px;"></img></span></span></div>');
    innerDiv.appendTo(outerDiv);
    $('#topSites').append(outerDiv);
})
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/QWAhV/

**side note**: instead of using `topPageTitle` you can just use the `index` variable which will return the page you are up to, like 'GOOGLE' , or 'YAHOO', fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/QWAhV/8/

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure whats wrong, it isn't showing up. And it's breaking a weather widget on the page (it uses jquery). (I tried using your new code too).

Comment: @NL2 did you look at the fiddle?

Comment: I just did, now it isn't breaking the weather widget. But it still isn't showing up. I've got the '<div id='topSites'></div>' too.

Comment: I just tried putting it in a fiddle, and it worked just fine (http://jsfiddle.net/NL2admin/T9cbd/). Hm.

Comment: emmm i see errors, can you add the plugin you are using to the resources?

Comment: Which plugin? I am calling about 9 different js resources. I just fixed it so that it works in the fiddle. But it still doesn't work in my actual page.

Comment: @NL2 still doesnt have the resources, and it throwing errors, look at js console

Comment: Which resources do you want? Is there a way I can just upload them, not use urls?

Comment: ehhh idk. u might have to upload them to a random site. look at the console to see what the errors are

Comment: Hm, ok, we'll see if I will upload them... I fixed all the errors (http://jsfiddle.net/NL2admin/T9cbd/2/) but it still won't work on my page.

Comment: @NL2 -- these are the errors i see in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
 } has no method 'simpleWeather'
fiddle.jshell.net:1416Uncaught ReferenceError: readCookie is not defined
fiddle.jshell.net:1567Uncaught ReferenceError: startTime is not defined`

Comment: That is just because some resources are missing. They shouldn't affect this. I fixed it! It had something to do with `$(document).ready(function () {` Which I thought was already there. But I guess not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hugh, my beautiful non JSON alternative syntax was pretty much ignored again hehehe. Personal note number 1 - never fork a answer from @Neal :D. Personal note number 2 - Don't post old school solutions. Personal note number 3 - Be the first to answer javascript questions at all costs :D (kidding!).

Comment: Not often (not a single occasion that I can remember). I'm just trying to get some empathy up votes for my answer. Stack Overflow is all about psychology and personality after all ;).

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating the DOM that heavily is known to be pretty slow. You can try things like:

- cache your reference to `$('#topSites1')` so jQuery doesn't have to search for it every time.
- Detach the node from the DOM, add your stuff to it, then re-attach it when it's ready. This will reduce a lot of DOM refreshes and possibly will show a decent performance improvement. To do this you need to use jQuery methods `detach()` and then `appendTo()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop by using the each function: [jquery .each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

Lets clean it with OO, old school style.

First, define a TopEntry "class":

```
function TopEntry(id, width, pageURL, pageTitle, rate, margin, sitesBack, pageFavicon) {
    this.id = id;
    this.width = width;
    this.pageURL = pageURL;
    this.pageTitle = pageTitle;
    this.rate = rate;
    this.margin = margin; 
    this.sitesBack = sitesBack;
    this.pageFavicon = pageFavicon;
    this.createDiv = function() {
        return $('<div class="meter-wrap" style="margin-top: ' + this.margin + 'px;"><div class="meter-value" style="background-color: ' + this.sitesBack + '; width: ' + this.width + '%;"><div class="meter-text"><span class="toplist"><span class="topnum">' + this.id + '. </span><span class="favico" id="ico' + this.id + '"><img src="img/blank.gif" style="width:16px;height:16px;"></img></span><a href="http://' + this.pageURL + '/">' + this.pageTitle + '</a><span class="rating" style="width: ' + this.rate + 'px;"><img src="img/blank.gif" style="width:100%;height:16px;"></img></span></span></div></div></div>')
    }
}
```

Then, lets declare an array and instantiate some TopEntry objects:

```
// create some array
var sites = new Array();
// Create object
var site = new TopEntry(1, 100, 'www.google.com', 'Google', rateStar9, 0, 'white', 'http://www.google.com/favicon.ico');
// push the object into the array
sites.push(site);
```

And finally the code to append the divs (considering that you are doing it at loading time):

```
// Manipulate DOM: Following Neal append Approach
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.each(sites, function (index, item) {
      $('#topSites').append(item.createDiv()); 
      $('#ico' + item.id).css('background', 'url(' + item.pageFavicon + ') no-repeat');
  });
});
```

As for the markup, all you need is a div acting as a container:

```
<div id="topSites"></div>
```

And of course, no javascript answer is ever complete without jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8duz/2/

Well, this is it ;).

Comment: Hum.. One thing, taking a look at other answers, I'm not sure if I interpreted topPageFavicon and topSitesBack correctly (as custom values for every website). If they are fixed values you can just remove them from TopEntry.